# How NOT to reload the entire page after POST

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a `CommandButton` when the user clicks it adds the selected records and post it to the `controller` but it repaint the entire page and I'm wondering how can I do using async in VFP without reloading the entire page?

```
   <apex:pageblock id="Selected_PBS" title="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0,'Selected Contact','There are no records selected')}">   
        <div align="center" style="padding:15px;" rendered="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0,'Selected Contact','There are no records selected')}">            
              <apex:commandButton value="Add to Work Order!" action="{!addToWO}" disabled="{!If(selectedContacts != null && selectedContacts.size > 0,false, true)}" />
        </div>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SelectedContacts}" var="contact" rendered="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0,true,false)}">
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Add a rerender to the command button

Comment: rerender what exactly?

Comment: just what ever you need to or nothing at all. But it does not make a good user experience to execute an action and have absolutely no indicator on the page that it actually happened. If you choose to serenader nothing simply add `rerender=""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the rerender attribute on the  tag. Give your pageBlockTable an id, then you can do something like:

```
<apex:commandButton rerender="[myPageBlockTableId]" ... />
```

This should make your action an ajax call.

Alternatively you can create remote actions in your controller and handle the dom manipulation yourself with a different client side framework. It's more low level but gives you more control.

Comment: i have implemented and let me play little bit more and see and also i have posted another question related to this but i have divided my question into two so the second question is here if you wanna look at it: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84122/how-to-display-confirmation-message-on-visualforce-page-ui